# Getting all sub directories using recursion

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, recursion, asp.net-mvc-4

I am fetching a list of all directories and sub directories in my computer.
I am using recursion.

Its ok until I perform the actuall recursion

I get this error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
at tgpwebged.Views.Admin.recursiveFileTree.WalkDirectoryTree(DirectoryInfo root) 
in s:\Projects\tgpwebged\tgpwebged\Views\Admin\recursiveFileTree.cs:line 93
```

**this is the class:**

```
static void WalkDirectoryTree(System.IO.DirectoryInfo root)
    {
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo[] subDirs = null;

        try
        {
            DirectoryInfo[] SubDirs = root.GetDirectories("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

            foreach(DirectoryInfo sdir in SubDirs) {
                log.Add(sdir.ToString());
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.Add("Exceção: " + e.ToString());
        }

        try
        {
            foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirInfo in subDirs)
            {
                log.Add(dirInfo.ToString());
                WalkDirectoryTree(dirInfo);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.Add("Exceção: " + e.ToString());
            log.Add("");
        }
     }
```

As you can see, the last for each gets the list of subdir in a dir and call the function again performing the recursion.

This class receive the all top directories from a Logical driver and go deep to the last directory structure.

Comment: Where do you ever set the value of subDirs? It's null.

Comment: What line is line 93 of `recursiveFileTree.cs`? That should give you a clue as to what the problem is. Though if I had to guess, I'd suspect the underlying problem is a stackoverflow somewhere. I believe if you dive into the guts of System.IO, you'll see it jumps into unsafe code to do its magic.

Comment: It doesen't make sense to eschew the `AllDirectories` option if you want to enumerate all directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You delcare `System.IO.DirectoryInfo[] subDirs = null;`

But you use `DirectoryInfo[] SubDirs`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have two different variable that are named the same thing with different cases:

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo[] subDirs = null;
DirectoryInfo[] SubDirs = root.GetDirectories("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

You are trying to iterate over `subDirs` but you never actually set it anywhere.

```
// subDirs is always null because you never set it to anything other than null
// in the variable declaration
foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirInfo in subDirs)
{
    log.Add(dirInfo.ToString());
    WalkDirectoryTree(dirInfo);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

C# is case sensitive,

`SubDirs` is not `subdirs`

You declare both, use both but only instantiate one.

---

Your sanitised **function** (not class) should be,

```
static void WalkDirectoryTree(System.IO.DirectoryInfo root)
{
    foreach(var subDirectory in root.GetDirectories(
        "*.*", 
        SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        log.Add(subDirectory.ToString());
    }
}
```

However, it would make sense to pass `log` into the function.